# What is the difference between "Node<T*> *first" and "Node<T> *first"?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I'm looking into implementing a linked list, using templates.

As it stands, after looking at some guides, I have managed to built a functioning one, but I am wondering what is the purpose of template pointer? The code seems to be using them arbitrarily. I'll exemplify on my header code below:

```cpp
template <class T>
class LinkedList{};

template <class T>
class LinkedList<T*>{
private:
    Node<T*> *first;
    int size;

public:

    class Iterator{

    public:
        Iterator(Node<T*> *newElem){
                elem = newElem;
        }
        virtual ~Iterator(){

        }

        T getValue(){
            return *(elem->getValue());
        }

        void next(){
            elem = elem->getNext();
        }

        void operator++(int i){
            next();
        }
        void operator++(){
            next();
        }

        T operator*(){
            return getValue();
        }

        bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs){
            return (elem == rhs.elem);
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs){
            return (elem != rhs.elem);
        }

        bool hasNext(){
            if (elem == NULL)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

    private:
        Node<T*> *elem;

    };
```

In this specific context, why do we need to declare the node variable or the linked list with < T *>? In my case, it works just fine using < T >, but I'm most likely missing something. The Node class(not listed above) is implemented using < T > as well, so what is actually happening when you add that pointer there?

Many thanks!

Comment: `LinkedList<T*>` is a specialization. Why do you use it and what is the primary template `LinkedList`? BTW, you hardly need a virtual destructor for the `Iterator`.

Comment: Added the primary template class as well. My bad! It's a generic linked list that uses nodes. I need it for multiple types of data(floats, strings and ints) that are read from a file, hence the use of templates.

Comment: Probably, you don't need a specialization for `T*`. Just put your code into the primary template and use `Node<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the content of your `Node`.

Let's define the `Node` class:

```
template <class T> 
struct Node
{
  T data;
  Node * next;
  Node * previous;
};
```

Let's use `int` as type `T` and instantiate:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node * next;
    Node * previous;
};
```

Let's use `int` and instantiate a `T *`, as in `Node<T*>` or `Node <int *>`:

```
struct Node
{
    int * data;
    Node * next;
    Node * previous;
};
```

Notice any difference in the data type of the `data` member?

In one example, `data` is an `int`.  In the other example, `data` is a *pointer to an*  `int`.

Comment: Yes, this is it! It makes sense now when I take a closer look at my Node class - it does have a template data member that's ok to default to a pointer. Thank you!